# Is my motherboard faulted?

Tags: windows-10, boot, motherboard

My girlfriend bought me a cheapish micromotherboard back at Christmas time and I wasn't complaining because I needed one. It worked fine up until now (I think).
I'll start from the beginning. I was using my PC as usual when everything started to run slow. I checked task manager and nothing was being used past 50%, except ram (8G) at about 65 ish. Everything was normal. So I thought "Ok, I'll just restart my pc". So I started the reboot and on the boot back up, it got to the Windows screen, loaded for about 2 minutes (usually it only took about 20 seconds) then got stuck on a black screen. The fans in my pc were still spinning so it was still obviously powered.
I tried to boot it back on after doing a number of things, all to no avail. So in the end I plugged in a flash drive with windows installer on it and formatted everything and reinstalled windows. Everything booted on the first start up, but it was still sluggish. After about 5 minutes (I let it sit there after getting to the homescreen) my pc black screened and rebooted by itself, no warning or reason. After that it would continiously go into the windows repair boot, sit there for about 5 minutes, then restart again.
So I formatted everything again and installed windows again just to be safe. Same result. I called it a night after that and went to bed.
The morning after I powered it on and it started working, still a little sluggishly, but it was operating. Everything on task manager was looking good, barely anything was being used, but the problem happened again. Random reboot out of nowhere, despite barely being taxed on Ram, CPU, or Disk.
That night (last night) I took everything apart and cleaned it with air, made sure thermal paste was ok, checked cpu pins, all that good stuff. I put it all together just now, and it boots up to the windows home screen, runs very sluggish, and after 2 minutes it reboots itself.

Additional information, I've checked all the connections and how loose they are, the motherboard, the whole computer, worked fine for 4 months, and I have changed the SETA cables I was using just to be sure. I also checked all the capacitors on the motherboard about 3 times.

My final question is this:
Is it a faulty motherboard or something else? And if its something else, any idea on what?

Comment: It's not likely a motherboard that was only used for 4 months is faulty.  However, electronics can fail, and when they fail weird things can happen.  What is more likely is a component within the computer failed (CPU, RAM, GPU, HDD, SSD, ect. )

Comment: Please include drive's SMART results and readings from temperature sensors. (use the [Edit] button)

Comment: To Ramhound, all the other parts are basically new as well, the HDDs and RAM being the oldest at 1 yearish. And if those were to fault, wouldn't task manager say something about it, and would that cause the pc to reboot in an insane loop.

Comment: @Hubz _"wouldn't task manager say something about it"_ - no. _"would that cause the pc to reboot in an insane loop"_ - maybe.